# method with int array as parameter

Tags: java

The task is:
Write an method printArray.
It shall take an int array as parameter.
It shall write every int in the array on a row (system out print)
If the parameter is null, nothing shall be written.

In my code I get this message: The method println(boolean) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (void).

```
MY CLASS:
public class Upg9_tenta {
    public static void printArray(int arr[]){
        int i = 0;
        while(i<arr.length){
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
            i++;

    }
}
}
```

MY MAIN:

```
public class Upg9_tentamain {
    public static void main (String []args){

        int []arr = {1, 3, 8, 6};

        Upg9_tenta.printArray(arr);

        System.out.println(Upg9_tenta.printArray(arr));


}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`printArray` returns `void`, so you can't actually print out its return value.

Just remove the line that calls `System.out.println` for that method, and you should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

`printArray()` is a `void` method, meaning that it has *no return value*. You can't pass something with no value to another method.

You already have a line that calls `printArray()` correctly, so remove this line

```
System.out.println(Upg9_tenta.printArray(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

`println()` method accepts the parameters, those parameters method will print on console.
In your case you are calling `printArray()` method is `void` method. 
[reference for println() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28char%29)

It is returning `void`, you have to either change return type of `printArray()` method or remove `Upg9_tenta.printArray(arr)` from `System.out.println()` method.

Modified Code :

```
 public class Upg9_tentamain {
        public static void main (String []args){

            int []arr = {1, 3, 8, 6};

            Upg9_tenta.printArray(arr);  // just call method to print array

            //Upg9_tenta.printArray(arr);         

     }
    }
```